# Why I get a problem that tells me to set the value to float, and when I do I get I need to set it to integer?

Tags: opencv, python-3.7

I'm trying to save a recording of camera, Im using a free course, and it says, I need to create cv2.VideoWriter.
the problem I get when I try is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ..., line 10, in <module>
    writer = cv2.VideoWriter(filename,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DVIX'),20,(width,height))
TypeError: a float is required
```

my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

width = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)

  #### THE PROBLEM IS IN THIS LINE ########

    writer = cv2.VideoWriter("images/my_super_vid.mp4",cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DVIX'),20,(width,height))

######################################

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    #OPERTAIONS (DRAWING ETC')

    writer.write(frame)

    cv2.imshow("frame",frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
writer.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I saw the problem and I changed it to:

```
writer = cv2.VideoWriter("images/my_super_vid.mp4",cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DVIX'),float(20),(width,height))
```

and even:

```
writer = cv2.VideoWriter("images/my_super_vid.mp4",cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DVIX'),20.0,(width,height))
```

but in both of those tries I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....", line 10, in <module>
    writer = cv2.VideoWriter("images/my_super_vid.mp4",cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DVIX'),20.0,(width,height))
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

I don't know how to fix it, I tried solutions I saw in the internet but none of them worked..
got the same problem

okay I changed the line to:

```
writer = cv2.VideoWriter("images/my_super_vid.avi",cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'),20, (int(width),int(height)))
```

and it worked. but now I get:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""
```

This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

when I try to run it in PyCharm
 FIXED IT: just ran it from terminal.

Comment: Try this for mp4, `writer = cv2.VideoWriter("images/my_super_vid.mp4", 0x7634706d, 20, (width,height))`.

Comment: same problem,: TypeError: a float is required

Comment: Try, `(int(width),int(height))`.

Comment: it worked :), but is there a way to know which param need to be float or int? because in PyCharm the params said `**args` and not the actual arg..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors are referring to different values on the same line in the parentheses. The first value has to be a float and second an int (or vice versa)

Comment: is there a way to know which one referring to which one?, Okay I guessed and it worked but now I get a new problem, edited on the question part of the post